# List of dependencies in Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, part-of-speech, dependency-parsing

I'm a beginner in NLP and i've decided to start with Spacy. It's simple to handle and to comprehend.
Neverthless, i can't acess to the full documentation or parsing.
I mean , i don't know the meaning of "IN" , "RB" for example
And, displacy that is used to display the dependency parsing doesn't show up a real information about the dependencies.
Exemple : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiXsA.png)

I understand the concept of dependency parsing, this example is in French.
What means the dependencies "Fixed" , "cop", "advmod" and finally where can i get a full documentation about it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what labels in spaCy mean by using [`spacy.explain`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level/#spacy.explain).

```
spacy.explain("NORP")
# Nationalities or religious or political groups

doc = nlp("Hello world")
for word in doc:
   print(word.text, word.tag_, spacy.explain(word.tag_))
# Hello UH interjection
# world NN noun, singular or mass
```

The dependency relations all come from [Universal Dependencies](https://universaldependencies.org/).

Comment: Thank you ! In particular for the link "Universal dependencies"